# Drupal_set_header returns error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, gd, readfile

ok , When i try to execute this routine , retrieves GD Error :

```
Function foo ()
{  
    $file_name = 'image1.jpg';
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    drupal_set_header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    drupal_set_header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
    readfile($file_name); 
}
```

**Error :**

```
The image http://192.168.1.190/parsegard/trackback/check/perm?pic=sites/default/files/imagecache/large/content_types/food_nutrition/2470/image1.jpg becuase it contains errors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make absolutely sure there is no other output on the page, not even leading or trailing spaces. This is the most common cause of this kind of error. Also turn off error outputting, log errors to a file instead. PHP errors can easily cause binary output to be corrupted too.

Locating the source of the unwanted output would be the optimal solution, but if you absolutely can't and just want it to work you could use [output control](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) as a workaround. Call `ob_start()` at the absolute beginning of your script (no preceding whitespace or other PHP code allowed), and `ob_end_clean()` at the absolute end of your script. Then place a call to `ob_clean()` at the beginning of your image outputting function, and a call to `ob_flush()` at the end of the function.

Comment: I try `error_reporting(0);@ini_set(‘display_errors’, 0);` but it contains errors agin, i use this routin in a simple php file and it works fine.

Comment: @bizzare: the problem is most likely that the image is not the only data being sent to the client. Temporarily remove the `readfile()` and set the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` to see what's hindering the image. Note that even a single space or newline can be the culprit!

Comment: OK i do this and discover a space when changing content type to text plain , how i can to remove that space or clean header output ?

Comment: @bizzare: check the rest of your code to see where the space is coming from. I'd start with the PHP opening and ending tags (`<?php` and `?>`), an accidental space/tab/newline before the `<` or after the `>` is a common occurence.

Comment: Ok ! im in a drupal module and check it for space and tabs and new lines before and after re `<` and `>`, but nothing found , is it drupal fault ?

Comment: @bizzare: it could be potentially anywhere, if it's not in an obvious location you'd have to use a systematic debugging approach to find it. If you'd rather use a workaround instead, check my updated answer.

Comment: Bingo ! finally i use `ob_end_clean();` to clear output buffer and now its works fine. Thanks for your direction